# More '%' conversions than data arguments

Tags: ios, image, uicollectionview, parse-platform

In a DetailView I am trying to show more than 1 image from Parse.com backend so I have this code:

EDIT:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

static int index = 1;
PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d", index ]];

[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


}
}];

return cell;
}
```

It works.. The problem is that once the user has viewed the images once they no longer appear again.

So I tried just implementing:

```
PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d"]];
```

But then I get the error of  "More '%' conversions than data arguments.
How do I set the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d"]];
```

To

```
PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%@", index ]];
```

When u write something like `NSLog(@" %d %f %@")`, u should pass arguments like this :

```
NSLog(@"%d %f %@", someInt, someFloat, someString);
```

You can try this:

```
PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d+1", indexPath.row ]];
```

Hope that help.

Comment: I get a Format String Issue: "Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char ()(const char*,int)' But if I keep: static int index = 1; Then a single image repeats itself in all cells.

Comment: Please try my updated answer. And tell us how exactly your image string look like, what is index? Show it in console

Comment: I did and I got that error. My strings are image_1, image_2, image_3 and so on.. I have edited my code and the way it is right now shows image_1 repeated in all cells.

Comment: You need to pass correct image string and change it for each cell, i guess you not changing image, you need to find a way to change it for each cell.

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you. Here is the code:  PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d", indexPath.row]];

Comment: Yes, there is it, you just need to use indexPath.row instead of index. If my answer was helpful, please mark it as correct, clicking "V" button below upvote-downlote frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an argument for the `%d` in the string format.

Perhaps you need this:

```
PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d", index]];
```

Comment: I get a Format String Issue: "Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *(*)(const char*,int)' But if I keep: static int index = 1; Then a single image repeats itself in all cells.

Comment: What is `index`? Is it an `int` or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is an int. I have edited my code. The way it is displaying now shows a single image in that case the first one repeating itself in all cells.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of all the answers in this questions I figured it out.

Here is the code for anyone who encounters the same problem:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d", indexPath.row]];

[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {

cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    }
}];

return cell;
}
```